# Wait for page transition to finish

Tags: flutter

How can I detect if a page transition was finished in flutter?

Background: When I pop to a page, I want to start a function after the page transition has finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register a callback when you `push` your new route that can also contain data from the popped route, if you need, for example, to pass data from it.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(/*Some route*/).then((data) {
 // You can call your function here. data will be null if nothing is passed from the popped route
});
```

If you want to pass `data` from the popped route, just do it like so

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(someData);
```

### Edited

If you want to know when the transition actually ***ends***, you can register a callback listener for it as well

```
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => RouteWidget())
                   ..completed.then((_) {print('transition completed');},
          ),
  );
```

Comment: But the callback of ```.then``` fires immediately after the page was popped. It does not wait for the transition to complete.

Answer (score 3):

Its also possible to wait for the push transition if you keep a reference to the route and using the didPush() TickerFuture

```
MaterialPageRoute route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyPage());
Navigator.of(context).push(route);
await route.didPush(); // you could also use then instead of await


// ROUTE FINISHED TRANSITION HERE
```

This can be used if you have multiple stacked navigators and you want smoother transitions between them. Like wait for Navigator 1 to finish the push before you pop the currently active Navigator 2 to show the page of Navigator 1

Answer (score 2):

#### Another solution

is to await the animation to finish on the second page (this is usefull if you want to update the page after the animation transition)

first page:

```
...
Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
            transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000), //optional but useful for testing
            pageBuilder: (_, animation, ___) => SecondPage(
                  pageBuilderAnimation: animation,
                )));
...
```

second page:

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage ({Key? key, this.pageBuilderAnimation});

  final Animation<double>? pageBuilderAnimation;

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

  bool isTransitioning = true;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.pageBuilderAnimation != null)
      widget.pageBuilderAnimation!.addListener(() {
        if (widget.pageBuilderAnimation!.isCompleted)
          setState(() => isTransitioning = false);
      });
    else
      isTransitioning = false;
  }
  ...
}
```